# Assigning values values to raster cells overlain by polygon layer using R?

Tags: raster, r, polygon, nodata

I have a raster layer and a polygon layer overlaying the raster. The thing is that I want to make a new raster as follows: 1) the extents of the new raster should be the same as the old raster. 2) The cells which are overlain by polygons should have a value of 1 and the parts which are not overlain by polygons, should have the value of zero.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] which is designed to introduce all users to this site and its protocols.  If you are not using R, then please ask a new question, and specify the GIS software that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not specify the software you are using, so I assume it is R. Here is how you can do it:

Some example data

```
library(raster)
pols <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))[1:3, ]
r <- raster(extent(pols), res=.01)
```

Solution

```
r <- rasterize(pols, r, field=1, background=0)
plot(r)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to say I'm using ArcGIS but I tried your advice in R and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the polygon to raster with class 1 (raster1). and reclassify your raster to have class zero(raster2). Then using "raster calculator", write this:

Con(IsNull(raster1),raster2, raster1)

So whenever the value exists in raster 1, it will be assigned to the cell; if no data in raster 1, it will take value from raster 2.